# Jenkins TestNG plugin not displaying the results

Tags: ant, jenkins, testng

I am using the Ant to build my project and run the testng tests. I am using jenkins to call the Ant targets to run the TestNG tests. Also have installed the TestNG plugin on jenkins running on same machine where my project is.

On completion of the Jenkins job, I am getting following  and TestNG results are not generated.

C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\jobs\Intel EAMP Automation\workspace>exit 0 
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: test-output/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: SUCCESS

My project folder is at location: E:\Project Folder\Framework\Project

which also has build.xml and testng.xml file along with the test-output folder(containing testng-results.xml file).

Please suggest how to configure jenkins to show the TestNG results...

Answer (score 0):

As explain [here](http://www.seleniumtests.com/p/testing-forum.html#nabble-td5001883), you have to use forward slash instead of back slash on Windows.

Comment: Tnx. However it requires the source code in the workspace folder. Is there any way where we can have the src folder outside the jenkins workspace.

Comment: Of course, go in <jenkins_url>/configure > Home directory > Advanced...

Here you can define the location of the workspace directory. Hope that helps.